# Python not importing module from same directory

Tags: python, import, directory

[They are in the same directory and I have the path set to the correct folder so I have no idea why it can't find the python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN3vP.jpg)

Expecting it to open the file to access a class.

Code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

import os

print("Working dir:", os.getcwd())

import OfficeContextAgent
```

Comment: Please include your code and full traceback error as text and not as images.

Comment: does it have the file extension `.py`?

Comment: are you sure you installed in python 3.9.7?

Comment: from your screenshot it looks like the `.py` is missing from the filename

Comment: Just double-checked for some reason it is a py in vsCode but not in the folder under properties that fixed it. I was also trying to use a decimal and underscore in the file name and that made python mad so I removed it and had no problems

Comment: or rather it having a python logo didn't mean it was necessarily a python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you name the file OfficeContextAgent.py and not just OfficeContextAgent. Python modules end in .py [ [docs.python.org entry on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules:%7E:text=The%20file%20name%20is%20the%20module%20name%20with%20the%20suffix%20.py%20appended.) ]